# My menu bar will not resize when window resizes

Tags: menu, resize, window, nav

I'm having problems with my code. I have a fixed menu bar that works as it should but it doesn't resize when I change the size of the window. I need it to resize because if you change the window size, it will will not scroll horizontally and some buttons are cut off. How can I fix this?

Also feel free to make optimization or input on unnecessary code
Thanks

```css
body {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 background: url(images/gradient.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-position: center;
}

section {
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 border-radius: 8px;
 background:#E5E7E9;
 width: 958px;
 height: 800px;
}

.bpic {
 width: 200px;
 height: 350px;
 margin: 0px;
}

.biopic {
 border: 2px solid #ddd;
 border-radius: 8px;
 padding: 5px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 350px;
 margin: 40px 40px 40px 375px;
}

.bio {
 margin: 40px;
 font-family: verdana;
 text-align: center;
}

#biography {
 font-family: arial black;
 font-size: 120%;
 text-align: center;
 border: 2px solid #ddd;
 border-radius: 8px;
 padding: 10px;
}

#assignments {
 font-family: arial black;
 font-size: 120%;
 text-align: center;
 border: 2px solid #ddd;
 border-radius: 8px;
 padding: 10px;
}

#projects {
 font-family: arial black;
 font-size: 120%;
 text-align: center;
 border: 2px solid #ddd;
 border-radius: 8px;
 padding: 10px;
}

#contact {
 font-family: arial black;
 font-size: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 border: 2px solid #ddd;
 border-radius: 8px;
 padding: 10px;
}

.email {
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 border-radius: 8px;
 padding: 5px;
 width: 150px;
 height: 96px;
 margin: 3px 40px 3px 400px;
}

.banner {
 width: 960px;
 height: 143px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0px;
 background: url(images/banner.png) no-repeat;
}

.banner h2 {
 font-family: vollkorn;
 font-size: 350%;
 color: white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
 top: -40%;
 left: 83%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.menu {
 list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #333;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(images/menu.jpg) repeat-x;
    position: fixed;
    min-width: 1080px;
 z-index: 1;
 display: inline-block;
}

.menu ul {
 float: left;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0 0 0 30%;
 list-style: none;
}

.menu ul li {
 padding: 0px;
 display: inline;
}

.menu ul li a {
    position: relative;
    float: center;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 180px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 0 0 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    outline: none;
    min-height: 24px;
}

.menu li a:hover, .menu li .current {
 position: relative;
 color: #ffffff;
 background: url(images/menuhoverright.jpg) top right no-repeat;
}

.menu li a:hover span, .menu li .current span {
 position: absolute;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 15px;
 height: 42px;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: url(images/menuhoverleft.jpg) no-repeat;
}

.jprop {
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 border-radius: 8px;
 padding: 5px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 195px;
 margin: 40px;
}

.jprop:hover {
 box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 140, 186, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>
  <!-- Homepage
    My Biography Page
    Author: 
    Date: 01/29/2017
  -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Homepage</title>
  <script src="modernizr-1.5.js"></script>
  <link href="homestyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <div class="menu">
   <img src="images/menu.jpg" alt="menu" />
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#biography"><span></span>Biography</a></li>
    <li><a href="#assignments"><span></span>Assignments</a></li>
    <li><a href="#projects"><span></span>Projects</a></li>          
    <li><a href="#contact"><span></span>Contact</a></li>
   </ul>   
  </div>
  
  <div class="banner">
   <img src="images/banner.png" alt="banner" />
   <h2>K V</h2>
  </div>
 
  <section>
   <div id="biography">
   <a name="biography"><h1>Biography</h1>
   </div>
   
   <div class="biopic">
   <img src="images/biopic.jpg" width="230" height="490" alt="biopic" class="bpic"/>
   </div>
   
   <article>
    <div class="bio">
    <p>Hello, my name is &&&&&&. --
    </p>
    <p>I am currently pursuing my A.S. degree in computer information technology at?I plan to start 
       working in the field of IT, once I obtained my A.S. degree and certifications. While working, I plan on 
       continuing my education to obtain my bachelor’s degree in IT at UCF. I have always had a passion for 
       technology, especially computers. To be able to work in the field that I enjoy is one of my life goal.  
    </p>
    </div>
   </article>
  </section>
  <br>
  <section>
   <div id="assignments">
   <a name="assignments"><h1>Assignments</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="jprop">
   <a href="Jprop/basic.html">
    <img src="images/jprop.JPG" alt="jprops">
   </a>
   </div>
  </section>
  <br>
  <section>
   <div id="projects">
   <a name="projects"><h1>Projects</h1>
   </div>
  </section>
  <br>
  <section style="max-height: 210px;">
   <div id="contact">
   <a name="contact"><h1>Contact</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="email">
   <a href="mailto:REDACTED">
    <img src="images/email.png" alt="emails">
   </a>
   </div>
  </section>
  <br>
 </body>
 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This bit of css from your style sheet is going to keep the menu from resizing below 1080px.  So it will be too wide for many tablets and phones for example.

```
   .menu {
        min-width: 1080px;
    }
```

Remove the min-width property, and see if that fixes it for you.

Comment: Removing it causes a problem where if the window is resized, all of the buttons shift below the menu bar.